# Any Characters Replace Increment Number

Tags: regex, notepad++

[image]

Is it possible when columns not align?

```
var[x];
var[x];
var[x];
var[x];
```

..

replace

```
var[0];
var[1];
var[2];
var[3];
```

Comment: If the text you want to change isn't vertically aligned, show us what it actually looks like.

Comment: i've added in question.

Comment: Do you want the `x` within those brackets to be the same number as in the other brackets on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sezer, here is an easy way to do it in Notepad++

1. In the Replace tab, make sure you check the "Regular Expression" box at the bottom left
2. Search: `(^\w+\[(\d+)\]=[^;]+;\w+\[)[^]]+`
3. Replace: `\1\2` or `$1$2` (depending on your locale, you may have to choose one or the other.)
4. Hit "Replace All"

Note that this will work for two variables on the same line, regardless of their name, for instance `firstvar[10]="asfa";somevar[x]="asdfas";`

If you want to replace only when the first variable is called kelimeler, change the search to:

```
(^kelimeler\[(\d+)\]=[^;]+;\w+\[)[^]]+
```

If you want to replace only when the first variable is called kelimeler and the second variable is called specialvar, use:

```
(^kelimeler\[(\d+)\]=[^;]+;specialvar\[)[^]]+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple script, for example in JavaScript:

```
var x=10;
for (var i=0;i<x;i++) {
    console.log('var['+i+'];');
}
```

with `var x` being the amount of rows you want to have

Then simply copy the logged output from your console.

Using such repetitive code does look awfully inefficient though. Almost every respectable programming/scripting language has some kind of incremental looping built in already. What is it you're trying to accomplish with this code? There is probably an easier way to do this.